# Nginx: Redirect https://www.domain.tld/target to https://nocache.domain.tld/destination

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain, cloudflare

I have a Cloudflare/Nginx(v1.8.0)/Apache server config with lots of caching.

Goal is to cache the main domain but allow access to a site via a subdomain on which all caching is bypassed.

So, I'm looking for a generic way of redirecting "https://www.domain.tld/target" to "https://nocache.domain.tld/destination"

A simple location match against the request_uri is enough for the non-www domain variant, but if the request comes in over the www subdomain, like many of the sites will, then it redirects to nocache.www.domain.tld which doesn't exist.

I've tried all kinds of different ways to remove the 'www.' substring, but nothing seems to work.

EDIT

Here is my non-working Nginx server config:

```
server {

  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;

  set $PROXY_DOMAIN_OR_IP $host;

  if ( $request ~* ".*(www\.)(.*)\/target" ) {
     set $host_without_www $2;
     return 302 $scheme://nocache.${host_without_www}\/destination;
  }
```

Comment: Could you post your Nginx config? You may have had a working rule, but had a rule which matched it before hand.

Comment: Thanks varlogtim.  Only just joined, so limited in the number of urls I can post.  Also my nginx config is quite large (Engintron).  That said, the problem can be boiled down to needing a way to create a $host_without_www variable, and then redirect to that instead of $host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working as follows:

```
location ~* "/target" {
  if ( $host ~* "www\.(.*)" ) {
    return 302 https://nocache.$1/destination;
  }

  return 302 https://nocache.$host/destination;
}
```

The 302's were for testing and will be changed to permanent redirects.

Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a location block that you can use for the redirection

```
server {
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    location /target {
        rewrite /target(.*)$ /destination$1 last;
        return 301 https://nocache.domain.tld$request_uri;   
    }
}
```

- The server_name limits the redirection to the `www.domain.tld` domain
- The location matches against all URIs that start with /target
- the rewrite directive converts /target to /destination and keeps anything that appears after
- The return pushes the redirect to the other domain
- you can also do this with proxy pass if you don't want the user to be redirected

Comment: Thanks, however I need the rule to cope with multiple domains.  I've got a similar location block to yours except that I want the return to be to something like: https://nocache.${domain}.${tld} with any 'www.' removed from $domain.

Comment: You do realize that you can't use multiple domains in your server block because you are using SSL, right?  So why are you redirecting to multiple domains?  In any case, it is super simple to right the regex that you want using the same format suggested above.  Good luck!

Comment: See server config above.  The server block serves multiple domains (not my config and works very well).  On the SSL matter, Cloudflare Flexible SSL sends https requests to port 80 of the origin server (nginx).